# Adding Search Nearby Side Panel To Custom Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm having difficulty integrating Google Places API with Google Map API.

I have the following custom code working for the custom styled map. However, the section where I am trying to add the search Nearby for restaurants, bars etc, is not working. I have been following and reading the documentation on this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#TextSearchRequests to try and understand and it's working. I'm hoping to have the actual side panel in my map. Thanks!

```
 <script>
window.onload = function () {
    var styles = [
        {
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#7da6d3' },
                { saturation: 8 },
                { lightness: -13 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'landscape.man_made',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#ffffff' },
                { saturation: -100 },
                { lightness: 100 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'road',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#7e90ad' },
                { saturation: -78 },
                { lightness: -8 },
                { visibility: 'simplified' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'poi.park',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#83cca5' },
                { saturation: -3 },
                { lightness: -16 },
                { visibility: 'simplified' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'poi.school',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#dddddd' },
                { saturation: -100 },
                { lightness: 22 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'poi.place_of_worship',
            elementType: 'all',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#dddddd' },
                { saturation: -100 },
                { lightness: 11 },
                { visibility: 'simplified' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'poi.business',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#96A6C5' },
                { saturation: 16 },
                { lightness: -20 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        },{
            featureType: 'transit',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { hue: '#7da6d3' },
                { saturation: 49 },
                { lightness: -12 },
                { visibility: 'on' }
            ]
        }
    ];

var options = {
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['Styled']
    },
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9534988, -75.1748003),
    zoom: 16,
    disableDefaultUI: false,
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'
};
var div = document.getElementById('googleMap');
var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);

var building = {lat: 39.9534988, lng: -75.1748003};
var image = 'images/marker.jpg';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: building,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});



var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: '1919 Market' });
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);
}

var request = {
     location: building,
     radius: '500',
     query: 'restaurant'
 };

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.radarSearch(request, callback);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that there's a lot things that you need to fix. For a beginner, I suggest that you need to take the full example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination), just modify it to incorporate the customization that you want.

Note: instead of using window.onload use the callback attribute in the script to specify the function that will be called after the api's are ready to be used. (see initMap in the code below).

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

**Update:**

You might need to study [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript/) to achieve what you want. Here is an  of [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) on how place search works.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm starting again from the starting place from that link. Quick question: do I need two API keys?? One from Google Places and one from Google Maps?? And is it possible to add the styles that I had in the previous example? THANKS!!

Comment: @Amanda you only need one. but you need to enable both API.. Styled Map is doable.

Comment: Hi, I started again from that example, and I've got the styling working, but what I am having difficulty doing is replicating how it functions as an actual Google Map, with the collapsable side panel that shows Nearby Places, not actually on the map, but in the panel you have the options to see Nearby restaurants, or Nearby Hotels. I can't find a working example of this or even a similar example in the Google documentation.

Comment: @Amanda I updated my answer. You may wanna accept the answer and create a new question if you needed more help so that you can get answers that is related to what you are currently encountering.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I should be starting a new question because what I'm trying to create hasn't actually changed. I've been trying to get the sidepanel all along.

Comment: @Amanda you need to use Places API and do javascript manipulation to populate the result in the panel.

Comment: hi, I guess I'm trying to get the search function onclick to simulate how it works in actual Google Maps.